# Prove that $\angle I_aB_0I_c=90$

Tags: geometry

> Given triangle $ABC$ and point $D$ on $AC$. Let $I_a, I_c$ be the centers of inscribed circles of $ABD$ and $BCD$ respectively. $B_0$ is the point, incircle of $ABC$ touches $AC$. Prove that $\angle I_aB_0I_c=90$

Solution: Let's say the foot of $ I_a, I_c $ on $ AC $ is $ A',C' $.
Then $ r_a \times r_c=A'D \times DC'=A'B_{0} \times C'B_{0} $ which means $ \angle{I_aB_0I_c}=90$.

This all makes sense to me except for the fact that $A'D \times DC'=A'B_{0} \times C'B_{0}$. We can get the first relation ($ r_a \times r_c=A'D \times DC'$) since the red triangles below are similar since they angles are from the angle bisectors. But I don't know how to get the second.

[image]

Comment: *the red triangles below are similar since their angles are from the angle bisectors* - I don't understand this sentence.

Comment: Didn't you rather mean $\angle{I_aDA'} = \frac{1}{2} \angle{\color{red}BDA'}$ and $\angle{I_cDC'} = \frac{1}{2} \angle{\color{red}BDC'}$ and $\angle{\color{red}BDA'}+\angle{\color{red}BDC'} = 180^{\circ}$ ?

Comment: @Lucian Yes, sorry typo. Do you see how they are similar now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows from basic rules about tangents to the incircle. We have

$$ A'B_0=AB_0-AA'=\frac{AB+AC-BC}{2}-\frac{AB+AD-BD}{2}=\frac{BD+CD-BC}{2}=C'D.$$